# What app do you prefer for flashcard use, pre-made?

Tags: vocabulary, resources, study-technique

There are plenty of Topik and flashcard apps but I'm being picky. I want decks of smaller sizes that cover most of the TOPIK books.

I specifically want an app that keeps track of the flashcards I don't get right so I can review them easily. A lot of the apps have spelling and multiple choice quizzes which is good, but I prefer more flashcard functionality.

At the end of the day if you could minimally recommend your fav app I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are many options of flashcards apps for learning foreign languages. Some of the ones I´ve used for TOPIK are [LingoDeer](https://www.lingodeer.com/) and [Duolinguo](https://www.duolingo.com/). They both offer interesting sources of vocabulary and grammar, but as far as I know, except for maybe LingoDeer, which mentions the test at their levels, they are not really focused on TOPIK vocabulary.

I would strongly recommend using vocabulary books like this [one](http://www.yes24.com/Product/Goods/57958962) and the more traditional [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) if you are an independent learner.

**Anki pros:**

- It is multi-platform, so it runs and syncs your progress on Windows, Android, iOS, from the web browser etc;
- You can pretty much add anything to the cards (video, audio etc) because it is based on HTML and JavaScript;
- Traditional [SRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) algorithm, based on SuperMemo SM2;
- Versatile import/export options;
- Costumizable flashcard layout, check [this](https://github.com/Troyciv/anki-templates-superlist);
- It is general use and free (except the iOS app, which is a different project and it is paid) and opensource, and you can copy text from your card and search for vocabulary on your favorite dictionary.
- Many plug-ins, like the [heatmap](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1771074083) and many [others](https://getpolarized.io/2020/02/14/Must-have-Anki-Add-ons-for-Medical-Students-in-2020.html)

[image: Anki heatmap example]

**Anki cons:**

- If you add many new cards, it can be really hard to do all the future reviews, because Anki focuses a lot on repetitions. Also, there is no simple option to set some learning conditions, like considering weekends as non-studying days. So expect a lot of card reviews from one week to another if you study many new cards on a given day.
- Anki 2.1 is based on a different ecosystem than Anki 2.0. So older plug-ins may not work on the latest version.
- As for Korean, I guess there might not be many pre-made decks as compared to Japanese for example.

My suggestion would be using Anki as a review tool for the new words you learn from TOPIK vocabulary books or from pre-made decks.